# Getting data fields AND associated entities into a Word file

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

*NB. This question might be a bit similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456443/connecting-data-source-from-crm-to-word-like-in-excel) but still result in a different answer, hence the division in two.*

I'd like to print out the contents of an entity, consisting of a subset of the fields and including some rudimentary information on its associated entities.

E.g. I'd like to print a lead by displaying its name and phone number but also a list of associated instances of type *new_somesome* (their *new_name* and *new_size*, for example) connected to it.

How can I do that?

I've tried cheating by using mail template but that doesn't include the related entities. I'm not sure how to edit the default print view to include the associatees neither.

Comment: If you don't mind to create your own application, I suggest to use DocX to manipulate the word document: https://docx.codeplex.com/

Comment: @GuidoPreite I do mind but I feel like I have no choice. Something needs to be done. I just can't believe that no one has come up with a solution to that before me (other than custom application).   :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it acceptable for you to use reports? 
For this purpose you can try free MS [ReportBuilder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116). MS allows to build reports without using such large tool as MS Buisness Intelligence. These custom reports appears to be more flexible than system ones. Another way is to try [Mail merge](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2012/11/14/mail-merge-in-crm-2011.aspx) functionality.

Comment: I didn't get Mail Merge to work fully. I need to list field values from the entity itself as well as **two** other associated custom entities (*N:1*). Also, I'd need preferably to set up a nice formatting, which in Word would be easy to achieve... Hints on that?